# How to check if a word exists in a text file using Python 3.3

Tags: python

The program is used to find anagrams for a inputted string. The possible anagrams come from a text file 'dict.txt'. However, I am trying to check if the inputted string is not in the dictionary. If the inputted string is not the dictionary, the program should not look for anagrams, and just print a message saying that the inputted string is not in the dictionary. Currently the code is saying that all of my inputted strings are not in the dictionary, which is incorrect.

```
def anagram(word,checkword):
    for letter in word:  
        if letter in checkword:  
            checkword = checkword.replace(letter, '') 
        else:  
            return False  
    return True  


def print_anagram_list():
    if len(word_list) == 2:
        print ('The anagrams for', inputted_word, 'are', (' and '.join(word_list)))
    elif len(word_list) > 2:
        print ('The anagrams for', inputted_word, 'are', (', '.join(word_list[:-1]))+ ' and ' +(word_list[-1]))
    elif len(word_list) == 0:
        print ('There are no anagrams for', inputted_word)
    elif len(word_list) == 1:
        print ('The only anagram for', inputted_word, 'is', (''.join(word_list)))        


def anagram_finder():
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word)==len(inputted_word):
            if word == inputted_word:
                continue
            elif anagram(word, inputted_word):
                word_list.append(word)
    print_anagram_list()


def check(wordcheck):
    if wordcheck not in f:
        print('The word', wordcheck, 'is not in the dictionary')


while True:
    try:
        f = open('dict.txt', 'r')
        word_list=[]
        inputted_word = input('Your word? ').lower()
        check(inputted_word)
        anagram_finder()
    except EOFError:
        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all of your words into a list beforehand:

```
with open('dict.txt', 'r') as handle:
    word_list = []

    for line in handle:
        word_list.append(line)
```

Replace `for word in f` with `for word in word_list` in your code, as now you have a list of all of the lines in the file.

Now, you can check if a word is in the list:

```
def check(wordcheck):
    if wordcheck not in word_list:
        print('The word', wordcheck, 'is not in the dictionary')
```

The `with` syntax lets you cleanly open a file without having to close it later one. Once you exit the scope of the `with` statement, the file automatically gets closed for you.

---

Also, you can simplify your anagram code a little bit:

```
def anagram(word, checkword):
    return sorted(word) == sorted(checkword)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still having trouble. Now the programs says that there is no anagram for any word that I type in. The 'not in dictionary' message still does not come up.

Comment: Is the word actually in the wordlist? No spaces or newlines at the end? Same case?

Comment: There is newlines at the end; I tried using .strip(), but I had no luck with that too.

Comment: Check to see if the word list doesn't contain whitespace or newlines.